# How to define default content for facet in a composite component?

Tags: jsf-2

I am trying to write a composite component in JSF 2.2.

This is it.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite">

        <!-- INTERFACE -->
        <cc:interface>
            <cc:facet name="content"/>
            <cc:facet name="menubar"/>
        </cc:interface>

        <!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
        <cc:implementation>
        Content header

        <cc:renderFacet name="content">
            This is the default content.
        </cc:renderFacet>

        Spacer

        <cc:renderFacet name="menubar">
            This is the default menubar.
        </cc:renderFacet>

    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

This is how it is used.

```
<dd:dummy>Hello hello</dd:dummy>
```

This is what is rendered to the client.

[image: output]

Why is the default content and default menubar not rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<cc:implementation>
    <c:if test="#{empty component.facets.content}" >
        This is the default content.
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{not empty component.facets.content}">
        <cc:renderFacet name="content"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{empty component.facets.menubar}" >
        This is the default menubar.
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{not empty component.facets.menubar}">
        <cc:renderFacet name="menubar"/>
    </c:if>
</cc:implementation>
```